# foreach is not a function in Angular 8

Tags: angular, foreach

I'm new to angular and started working on angular with foreach. I created a list of values and when tried to iterate the same using Foreach, I'm getting an console error stating ".foreach is not a function".

```
selectedNames = ["John","Alex"]

this.selectedNames.forEach(x => console.log(x));
```

the console error which gets when executed is

```
VM28872 TreeChecklistExample.ngfactory.js:304 ERROR TypeError: this.selectedNames.forEach is not a function
    at TreeChecklistExample.testclick (VM28712 tree-checklist-example.ts:236)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (VM28872 TreeChecklistExample.ngfactory.js:310)
    at handleEvent (view.ts:138)
    at callWithDebugContext (services.ts:639)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (services.ts:375)
    at dispatchEvent (util.ts:134)
    at eval (element.ts:195)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eval (dom_renderer.ts:52)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:265)
```

Comment: It works at my end.

Comment: Could you please some code in your ts file (`tree-checklist-example.ts`)? Because this data is not enough for solving error?

Comment: Reproduced your code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ozjvb and it works fine..

Comment: value of this.selectedNames might be not an array. that's why you got TypeError.

Comment: @ranjitredekar, yeah the value is of string type , the value which passed into selectedNames, didn't came as array type. Thanks fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by other commentors, check whether the SelectedNames input is provided as Array values. Most of the time, they may not and result in error while using foreach